# Поэтому били лётчиков враги(,) как детей!

Tags: пунктуация

> Подготовка лётная была никудышная. Поэтому били лётчиков враги(,) как
> детей!

Запятая нужна здесь?

Answer (score 1):

*Подготовка лётная была никудышная. **Поэтому били **лЁтчиков** враги, как детЕй!***

Запятая ставится, сравнительный оборот (*летчиков, как детей*) имеет значение **уподобления**.

В предложении используется **инверсия** (прямой порядок: *враги били летчиков, как детей*).  В этом случае слово "летчиков" подчеркивается логическим ударением.